# Mongo database objects says undefined if do not check for err

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am currently trying to learn how to use MongoDB. I tried two similar but slightly different pieces of code and received completely different results. I am trying to understand why this happened.

**CODE 1**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err,     client) {
    if (err) throw err

    var db = client.db('EmployeeDB')
    var cursor = db.collection('Employee').find()
    cursor.forEach(function(err, doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        console.log("Hello")

    });
    client.close()
});
```

**CODE 2**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, client) {
    if (err) throw err

    var db = client.db('EmployeeDB')
    var cursor = db.collection('Employee').find()
    cursor.forEach(function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(doc);
        }

    });

    client.close()
});
```

Code 1 returned "undefined \n undefined \n undefined". However, Code 2 returned the actual objects and their information. I was wondering why only the second piece of code works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one argument in the callback of cursor.forEach(), not two. Hence in both cases, "doc" is not defined, and only "err" is defined (which is the actual document).

Your code should thus be:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var db = client.db('EmployeeDB');
    var cursor = db.collection('Employee').find();

    cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc);
    });

    client.close();
});
```

From MongoDB official docs:

> The  signature includes a single argument that is passed the current document to process.

Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/